# How to match Russian words using preg_match php

Tags: php, regex, utf

I want to match the Russian words using preg_match in php

i tried below examples but it is not working

`"/\b".$word."\b/i"`

```
'/(?<!\pL)'.$word.'(?!\pL)/iu'
```

`/\b'.$word.'\b/iu`

```
'/'.$find_ru.'/iu'
```

e.g

Input

```
$word = "королевства";

$russian_string = "источники в спецслужбах королевства";


if(preg_match('/'.$word.'/iu', $russian_string)){ 
   echo "Matched";
}else{ 
   echo "Not Matched";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please, provide input strings and expected output. Thank you.

Comment: okay and thanks @Syscall

Comment: @Syscall now is it okay?

Comment: Perfect, Ganesh :)

Comment: This code works, except a syntax error : missing a closing bracket after `$russian_string)`. Should be `$russian_string)) {`.

Comment: Thanks and any positive solution from you for this quesry?

Comment: sorry for this syntax error but it not working @Syscall

Comment: Seems to work as expected : https://3v4l.org/Zc7SK

Comment: @Syscall its working fine on blank slate but actually i am using [http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/] to parse url then using string as `$element->plaintext` i think here is issue

Comment: So, please, provide a `var_dump()` of your `$element->plaintext`, or something that we can test to help you.

Comment: here is var_dump

`string(72444) " RT на русском: последние новости в России и в мире онлайн RT на русском Вконтакте"`

Comment: `string(72444)` !! Outch.. :) Seems to have _many_ unvisible things! Maybe, update your question (or create new) to explain this specific issue (and add code you use to get this element).

Answer (score 0):

Missing closing bracket in `if` condition

```
$word = "королевства";
$russian_string = "источники в спецслужбах королевства";

if(preg_match('/'.$word.'/iu', $russian_string, $word)){ 
    echo "Matched";
}else{ 
    echo "Not Matched";
}
```

Output will be `"Matched"`

Or you can do like this way also,

```
$haystack = "источники в спецслужбах королевства";
$needle   = "королевства";

if( strpos( $haystack, $needle ) !== false ) {
    echo "Matched";
}else{
    echo "Not Matched";
}
```

Output will be "Matched"